# ksqlDB java client: not able to deserialize data from client.executeStatement()

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform, ksqldb, confluent-cloud

I am trying to query a KSQL Stream on confluent cloud using Java ksqlDb-api-client:0.24.0 using the below code

```
        ClientOptions options = ClientOptions.create()
                .setHost(KSQLDB_SERVER_HOST)
                .setPort(KSQLDB_SERVER_HOST_PORT)
                .setUseTls(true)
                .setUseAlpn(true)
                .setBasicAuthCredentials(USER_NAME,PASSWORD);

        Client client = Client.create(options);
        Map<String, Object> properties = Collections.singletonMap("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");

        client.streamQuery("select * from process_payments EMIT CHANGES;", properties)
                .thenAccept(streamedQueryResult -> {
                    System.out.println("Query has started. Query ID: " + streamedQueryResult.queryID());
//                    RowSubscriber subscriber = new RowSubscriber();
//                    streamedQueryResult.subscribe(subscriber);

                }).exceptionally(e -> {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Request failed: " + e);
                    return null;
                });
```

Even with the RowSubscriber is commented out, I am still getting the below exception, FYI my msg is as simple as a single String column for ease of debugging:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/confluent/ksql/schema/utils/FormatOptions
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil.getClassMethods(ClassUtil.java:1231)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.confluent.ksql.schema.utils.FormatOptions
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 92 more

Request failed: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Failed on call to `getDeclaredMethods()` on class `io.confluent.ksql.schema.ksql.LogicalSchema`, problem: (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError) io/confluent/ksql/schema/utils/FormatOptions
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"queryId":"transient_PROCESS_PAYMENTS_2977877146871246906","columnNames":["STATUS"],"columnTypes":["STRING"]}"; line: 1, column: 1]
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you'll need to add ksqldb-udf to your classpath.  That jar contains `FormatOptions`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Geo, adding "ksqldb-udf" solved the issue to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to version conflict. I'm also getting the exact same error with version `7.2.1`. It's working fine in version`6.0.1` without additional dependency.